# Excel like HTML table scrollable on x-axis (full table) and y-axis (header fixed)

Tags: html, css

I want to build a table that has fixed width columns. The table data will in most cases overflow both horizontally and vertically.

If the width of the columns is greater that the view width, an horizontal scrollbar is needed to scroll and see all table columns, scrolling both header and data.

If the height of data is greater than the available view, than a vertical scroll box appears, but on scrolling keeping the header fixed so that the user keep an eye on columns.

It is an Microsoft Excel like behaviour (just for reading). Something like:[image]

I've seen several posts, but they only solve either the horizontal scroll or the vertical scroll. I need a solution that will work on both conditions on the same time.

[Here is a FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d13d2fab/1/)  I'm trying to make work, but even a simple horizontal scroll using `overflow-x: auto` is not working. I need a plain HTML + CSS to embed in a ReactJS component.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with plain HTML + CSS (no JavaScript).  I'd love to be corrected if I'm wrong.  Can you use JavaScript (since you are using react)?

Comment: Pure JS ok. Can't support jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, this would need a little tweaking to get it perfect, but I am assuming that you are not leaving all those bright red borders, etc. anyway.  I took the liberty to make the columns larger (force-width to 400px) to better demonstrate the effect.

Essentially, there is a `position:absolute;` that has it's `top` forced on scroll to equal the scrollTop of the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/d13d2fab/3/

```js
document.querySelector('.ux-data-table').onscroll = function (e) {
  // called when the window is scrolled.
  var topOfDiv = Math.max(document.querySelector(".ux-data-table").scrollTop - 2, 0);
  document.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0].style = "top:" + topOfDiv + "px;";
}
```

```css
.ux-data-table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Prevents the header from overflowing the scrollbars */
.ux-data-table-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.ux-data-table table {
  width: 100%;
}

.ux-data-table table,
.ux-data-table th,
.ux-data-table td {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  min-width: 400px;
}

.ux-data-table thead {
  position: absolute;
}
.ux-data-table tbody {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:block;
}
.ux-data-table td {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='ux-data-table'>
  <div class='ux-data-table-inner'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Col 1</th>
          <th>Col 2</th>
          <th>Col 3</th>
          <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>CD player</td>
          <td>Used</td>
          <td>Sony</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>Variscope</td>
          <td>Used</td>
          <td>General</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Item 3</td>
          <td>Microphone</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Mastersound</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Cable</td>
          <td>New</td>
          <td>Techable</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I liked the trick to move the header, but there is a problem if the whole table content fits on screen horizontally. Tried width: `50px` and `min-width: 50px` where it is currently 400px and the vertical scroll remained on the right side of screen, not on table itself....

Comment: Just add a `float:left;`.  I also added a `max-width` to the cell columns: http://jsfiddle.net/d13d2fab/4/  If necessary, you can add a `div` with `clear:both` so that the subsequent DOM does not wrap around it.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, but I still can´t make it work, as all of my columns has fixed width, different per column. To respect the widths I´m using `table-layout: fixed` and that is breaking something.... I´m lost here... Help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have it in a fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k5k7vtwu/. Does not contain the `table-layout: fixed` attribute on table class.

Comment: Can you use `nth-child` to fix the width per column?  http://jsfiddle.net/k5k7vtwu/1/

Comment: I can´t. These widths comes from user preferences from database. Cannot be set on classes, but on code loading (I´m using ReactJS). It must be a parameter that applies on runtime to `td` and `th` styling.....

Comment: Can you load it into the `<td>` and `<th>` when you are generating it with ReactJS, then?  http://jsfiddle.net/k5k7vtwu/2/

Comment: Yes, I can. But repair in your fiddle that the column is not respecting the set `width`, but calculating by itself (the column is not the width that it is set to in the HTML code). For what I´ve seen the `<td>` and  `<th>` widths will only have effect if `table-layout: fixed` is set, but in that case nothing happens if I set it on `table`.

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing that?  I don't understand.  For me, the widths are exactly as I specified in the HTML.  I checked in Chrome and Firefox.